# how to fix stale element not found error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm holding my head over an error that came out of creating code that automatically flipped pages during a simple crawl operation. I wondered if it was a problem with the page loading time, so I put enough `time.sleep`, but no matter how I tried, I got an error message. How can I fix this error?

**MY CODE :**

```
    def move_next(driver):
    
        for page in pages:
            page_num = page.text.strip()
    
            time.sleep(5)
            if page_num in [last_page]:
        
                pass
            elif page_num == '다음':
                page.send_keys("\n")
                driver.implicitly_wait(5)
                time.sleep(3)
        
                return False
            elif int(page_num) == int(page_now):
                WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/section/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/span[2]/a[2]"))).click()
                driver.implicitly_wait(3)
                time.sleep(3)
            
                return False
        
            elif int(page_num) >  int(page_now):
                page.send_keys("\n")
                driver.implicitly_wait(5)
                time.sleep(3)
        
                return False
            else:
                print('마지막 페이지')
      
                return True

    is_done = False

    while(not is_done) :
        time.sleep(5)
        is_done = move_next(driver)
```

**Error Message**

```
StaleElementReferenceException            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 5
      3 while(not is_done) :
      4     time.sleep(5)
----> 5     is_done = move_next(driver)

Cell In[19], line 5, in move_next(driver)
      2 def move_next(driver):
      4     for page in pages:
----> 5         page_num = page.text.strip()
      7         time.sleep(5)
      8 #     반복 중 마지막 페이지 상태일 시 패스

StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found
```

Comment: Please always provide a minimum reproducible work/code snippets in order to reproduce the error and thus provide you some work around to solve it.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: this is only part of the code. the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example